# Are there general guidelines to make "assumptions" when proving limits?

Tags: limits, proof-verification

I am studying the definition of the limit using [Paul's Online Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DefnOfLimit.aspx)

When proving the following limit (Example 3)

$\lim\limits_{x \to 2} x^2+x-11 = 9$

At one point he assumes:

$|x+5| < K$

He also asumes:

$|x-4| < 1$

Because one is a nice number to work with.

I have read multiple explanations and every author seems to make their own "assumptions" when dealing with limit proofs. So my question is:

Why the assumptions they make are right?

Lets say I have to prove the following:

$\lim\limits_{x \to 4} x = 2$

While the above is impossible, what stops me from making my own "assumptions" like 2=4 to prove the limit?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may not make absurd assumptions such as $2=4$.  However, making assumptions about $x$ is perfectly legal so long as it coincides with we want to prove.

When dealing with limits, as in Paul's example, we can restrict our attention only to neighborhoods close to our point of interest.

Take for an exaggerated example $\lim\limits_{x\to 5} f(x)$ where $f(x)=\begin{cases} \text{something overly complicated and ugly to work with}&x\geq 6\\ 2 & 4\leq x<6\\ \text{something else incredibly complicated}&x<4\end{cases}$

If I try to analyze the function outside of the range $[4,6)$, then I will have an incredibly difficult time going about it.  However, it doesn't matter at all what is going on outside of that range since we are asking about finding the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to 5}f(x)$.  By restricting our attention to when $x$ is within a neighborhood of $5$ (since we only care about what happens in a neighborhood of $5$), we see that whenever $|x-5|<\delta~~~(0<\delta\leq 1$ in this case $)$, in otherwords, $x\in (5-\delta, 5+\delta)$, you fall entirely within the easier case of the piecewise defined function that I defined above, and the function is incredibly easy to work with.  Within that neighborhood, the function is equal to precisely 2.  It follows that in my example $\lim\limits_{x\to 5} f(x) = 2$ since whenever $|x-5|<\delta<1$ you have $|f(x)-2|=|2-2|=0<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

In much the same way, Paul has decided to use the fact that he only cares about the properties of his function near the point in question (in his example $\lim\limits_{x\to 4} x^2+x-11$), so by restricting his attention to a small enough neighborhood around the point, he could understand the structure of the function more easily than otherwise.

---

A friendly reminder, in proving limits with an epsilon-delta argument:

> $\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x) = L$ if and only if for every $\epsilon$, there exists a $\delta$ such that whenever $0<|x-c|<\delta$ it follows that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

Comment: The original expression was $|x+5||x-4|< \epsilon$, but Paul choose to restrict only $|x+5|$ Doesn't that affect the "balance" of the expression?

Comment: If you look carefully, he just says that $|x+5|<K$ for some $K$ *large enough*.  Indeed, by picking $K$ to be... say... 100, this essentially restricts our focus to the range $x\in (-105,95)$, which is still a neighborhood of $x=4$.  Later in his proof, he decides to specifically use $K=10$ since $|x-4|<1$ implies that $x\in (3,5)$, a subset of $(-15,5)$ which is what $|x+5|<10$ would require to be true.

Comment: Once he decided that he was interested only in the neighborhood of distance 1 around $x=4$ (i.e. $(3,5)$, i.e. $|x-4|<1$), then the condition that $|x+5|<10$ was automatic.

Comment: Why he chooses $K$ to be large when the limit is at 2? And how $(-15,5)$ is a subset of $(3,5)$?

Comment: His target is at $c=4$, not $2$.  $(-15,5)$ is not a subset of $(3,5)$, it is a super set.  $(3,5)$ is the subset of $(-15,5)$ because every number in $(3,5)$ is also in $(-15,5)$ (here we are using interval notation, $(3,5)$ is the set of all $x$ such that $3<x<5$).  It doesn't matter what $K$ is until later in the proof as he explains.  Essentially, he decided to look only at the $x$ near to $4$ (within distance 1 from 4) and found that to guarantee $|f(x)-9|<\epsilon\leq 10$ that $|x-4|<\frac{\epsilon}{10}$ sufficed, and for $|f(x)-9|\leq 10<\epsilon$ that $|x-4|<1$ sufficed.

Comment: Ok, Sorry for the confusion, I couldn't edit my comment as 5 mins passed